# How to drop some observations based on the value of one variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset when I have three variables which can take the following values `-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
For some reason, I only want to work with these variables when the observations are equal to `1, 2, 3, 4 or 5`. In other way, I want to drop observations when `var1/var2/var3=-2, -1 or 0`
I know in Stata this is made with the command `DROP` (`drop if var1 == 0 / drop if var1<0...`). Is there a similar equivalent in R? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to R (and SO)! if `vec` is the variable with your numbers, then you can either do `vec <- vec[ !vec %in% c(-2, -1, 0)]` for a "set" exclusion, or `vec[ vec > 0]` for inequality. You can go further with `vec[ vec < -2 | vec > 0 ]` if you want to exclude a range, or `vec[ 0 < vec & vec <= 5]` if you want an inclusive range.

Comment: You may find that this type of question is well handled in R tutorials, and (as you have already received one down-vote) some SO frequenters consider this a poor question. I think it's good to learn the language, but SO is not great at being a tutorial site, so please consider looking at some R tutorials. There are some that have STATA-language for those wishing to convert, though I don't know anything about their quality (I don't know STATA). Good luck, Carlos! (And by "some", I mean that I did a quick google search for `transition from stata to r`.)

Answer (score 0):

If your data.frame is `df`, one way to do it would be like this...

```
df <- data.frame( #an example
        var1 = c(1, 2, 3),
        var2 = c(-1, 3, 4),
        var3 = c(2, 3, -2)
      )

df
  var1 var2 var3
1    1   -1    2
2    2    3    3
3    3    4   -2

df[apply(df, 1, function(x)
          ! any(x %in% c(0, -1, -2))), ]

  var1 var2 var3
2    2    3    3
```

The `apply` function runs down the rows of `df` and is `TRUE` for the rows that do not (`!`) have `any` value in the set `c(0, -1, -2)`.  This logical vector is then used to subset the rows of `df`.